# SSR in vue js, error while clicking anything

Tags: vue.js, webpack, server-side-rendering

I have implemented SSR in vue js using Webpack. When I try it normally without build it works fine, but when I try with build I am not able to see any of the click event.
Can anyone please help me to get out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: posting some code would be nice!

Comment: https://medium.com/better-programming/vuejs-server-side-render-with-vue-router-e73d51699873

I have taken guidance from this link, but now I am not able to perform any click